# Excel VBA .Find Method isn't finding what I know is there

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large table of data that needs to be broken up into several smaller tables and reorganized. I want to Autofilter the large table, run down a list of values to find in the large table, and compare the values in the cells next door to values on a pre-existing table. Here's the code I wrote:

```
Set rData = wsData.Range("A1:P7000")
rData.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=sSensor
Set rBand = wsNew.Range("C1")
For iBand = 1 To 149
    dFreq = rBand.Offset(iBand, 0)
    Set rNew = rData.Find(dFreq, , xlValues)
    If Not rNew Is Nothing Then
        If rNew.Offset(0, 1).Value > rBand.Offset(iBand, 2).Value Then
            rNew.Offset(0, 1).Copy
            rBand.Offset(iBand, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The problem I'm having is that the `If Not rNew Is Nothing Then` line always comes back false, even when I can verify that the value in `dFreq` exists within `rData`.

**UPDATE**

I've changed the code as shown:

```
Set rData = wsData.Range("A1:P7000")

'New
rData.Copy
wsData.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'/New

rData.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=sSensor
Set rBand = wsNew.Range("C1")
For iBand = 1 To 149
    dFreq = rBand.Offset(iBand, 0)
    Set rNew = rData.Find(dFreq, , xlValues)
    If Not rNew Is Nothing Then
        If rNew.Offset(0, 1).Value > rBand.Offset(iBand, 2).Value Then
            rNew.Offset(0, 1).Copy
            rBand.Offset(iBand, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This appears to work about 99% of the time. Occasionally, `rNew.Offset(0, 1).Copy` will copy the wrong cell for some reason. For example, one iteration found the `dFreq` value in cell I467, but copied cell K452 (the first row of the filtered table) instead of J467. Also, once in a while, `rNew.Offset(0, 1).Value` = Error 2040.

Comment: Should you be searching for `dFreq.Value`?

Comment: Try: "If Not (rNew Is Nothing) Then"  The Not operations mostly takes precedent over the Is. So if rNew has value it is most likely being converted to false which is not equal to nothing.

Comment: Try not to filter first?

Comment: I think BruceWayne is right, because dFreq returns range. I would do `dFreq = rBand.Offset(iBand, 0).value` and dimension it as a string or something.

Comment: Top 3 things to eliminate: 1) check the search value isn't a date, 2) pass all the `Find` arguments, 3) check search value is what you think it should be ... default property is `.Value` but I'd use `.Value2` in case you have used some rounding or formatting.

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne and @RyszardJędraszyk for the suggestion. I didn't even notice the missing `.Value` beacuse `dFreq` showed the correct value in the watch window. Changing the line to `dFreq = rBand.Offset(iBand, 0).Value` did not fix the issue.

Comment: @findwindow : The value I'm trying to find shows up in the table multiple times. I'm using the filter to control which iteration it looks for.

Comment: @Ambie - 1) The value is not a date. It is 21.1602429208891 and I have `dFreq` declared as `Double`. 2) Changing `.Value` to `.Value2` doesn't resolve the issue. 3) This is curious. When I do the find manually, it says "Excel cannot find the data you're searching for." But if I copy the cell and paste values somewhere else, the find works. It looks like I might have to do a Copy/Paste Values to the entire table first.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because you're mixing ranges. `rBand` is a `Range`, and so `rNew` can be looked at like `Set rNew = rsData.Range("A1:P7000").find(wsNew.Range("C1").Offset(iBand,0),,xlValues)`  ...which should work, I just think the mixing of ranges might be an issue?  What data is in `wsNew.Range("C1").Offset(iBand,0)`, or is expected to be in there?

Comment: @BruceWayne I tried changing rNew to a variant instead of a range, but it didn't help.